# Why am I getting this WCF Error Message?

Tags: wcf, web-services

I am getting the error below when I call my WCF service.  What am I missing here?

```
'System.String[]' with data contract name
'ArrayOfstring:http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays'
is not expected. Add any types not known statically to the list of known
types - for example, by using the KnownTypeAttribute attribute or by adding
them to the list of known types passed to DataContractSerializer.'.  Please
see InnerException for more details.

{"There was an error while trying to serialize parameter
http://tempuri.org/:myEntity. The InnerException message was
'Type 'System.String[]' with data contract name
'ArrayOfstring:http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays'
is not expected. Add any types not known statically to the list of known
types - for example, by using the KnownTypeAttribute attribute or by adding
them to the list of known types passed to DataContractSerializer.'.  

Please see InnerException for more details."}
```

Comment: can you post the code to your service and/or client?

Comment: am new to WCF...myEntity is a C# businessobject...can u please let me know how and where do I supply this type to DataContractSerializer ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From what I gather, you have a WCF function that has a parameter named 'myEntity'.  I'm assuming that the type of myEntity is a user-defined class and is adorned with the DataContract attribute, as it should be.  I'm also assuming that the type of myEntity has a member field that is a string array.  Let's assume that all of this is true (again, it'd be really helpful if you could post your code).

Ordinarily, string arrays, i.e., string[], will serialize just fine.  But, in some cases (see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa347850.aspx) and [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/sowmy/archive/2006/06/06/all-about-knowntypes.aspx)), you may have to add it to the list of known types in order for WCF to serialize everything correctly.

To do this, add the following:

```
[DataContract]
[KnownType(typeof(string[]))]
public class YourClassNameHere
{
}
```

Comment: bang on target Matt...works like a charm!:-)thanks for ur answer!

Comment: what about is i get this error and i don't have a custom class ? I just want to pass a parameter who happens to be a string[].

Answer (score 5):

You haven't posted the code, so my answer is based on the assumption that you have a class myEntity which you are trying to serialize. Try using a KnownTypeAttribute for the class

e.g.

```
[KnownType(typeof(myEntity))]
```

You can refer to the following MSDN link:
[KnownTypeAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.knowntypeattribute.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Yes. As explained in the previous post, The issue occurs if you pass an array of a Type(which is defined as a DataContract]). you will need to define the array of this class as a seperate type and mark it as data contract.

Wont Work`

```
[DataContract]
Public class ABC{
}

...

SendData(ABC[])
```

`

What will work:

```
Public class Data{ public ABC[] prop{get;set;}}
...
SendData(Data);
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, after adding [Serializable] attribute to the MyEntity class. And then the issue came with serialization of the roles string array.

```
    [Serializable]
    [KnownType(typeof(string[]))]
    public class MyEntity
    {
       .........
       public string roles[]
       ......... 
    }
```

[KnownType(typeof(string[]))] worked like magic!