# DataContract Serialization for HashSet

Tags: .net, serialization, hashset

I am trying to Serialize a HashSet as the below code.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication20
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var sr = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(Test));
            var t = new Test();
            var mem = new MemoryStream();
            sr.WriteObject(mem, t);

        }


    }

    [DataContract]
    public class Test
    {
        [DataMember]
        public ISet<int> TestSet = new HashSet<int>();
    }
}
```

But this code fails with:

*Type 'System.Collections.Generic.HashSet`1[[System.Int32, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]' with data contract name 'ArrayOfint:http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays' is not expected. Consider using a DataContractResolver or add any types not known statically to the list of known types*

I definitely don't want to touch this line :

```
  public ISet<int> TestSet = new HashSet<int>();
```

In addition to that for some other reason (the type is not actually hashset) I am not allowed  HashSet as a known type for this case.
What should I do ?

Answer (score 2):

I´m not sure why you get the exception, because changing the TestSet to another type (like `IEnumerable<int>`) will not result in an exception. But adding

```
[KnownType(typeof(HashSet<int>))]
```

to your class solves your problem.

```
[DataContract]
[KnownType(typeof(HashSet<int>))]
public class Test
{
    [DataMember]
    public ISet<int> TestSet = new HashSet<int>();
}
```

See also this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/800358/why-am-i-getting-this-wcf-error-message) for more information.

Comment: I can't use known type here because it's actually not hashset but sometime that is inaccessible to this assembly

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest creating a public property based on your hashset.

```
public ISet<int> TestSet = new HashSet<int>();

[System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMember]
public int[] TestArray
{
    get { return TestSet.ToArray(); }
    set { TestSet = new HashSet<int>(value); }
}
```