# WCF Comunication Exception when passing string array

Tags: string, wcf, wcf-binding

I have a wcf service and i want to pass a `string[]` through it. I am receiving the below error. Can someone point me in the right direction ?

The error :

> There was an error while trying to serialize parameter http://services.csssoftware.com/2.0/ComFacades:arParams. The InnerException message was 'Type 'System.String[]' with data contract name 'ArrayOfstring:http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays' is not expected. Consider using a DataContractResolver or add any types not known statically to the list of known types - for example, by using the KnownTypeAttribute attribute or by adding them to the list of known types passed to DataContractSerializer.'.  Please see InnerException for more details.

If you need more data plese let me know and i will edit the question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why am I getting this WCF Error Message?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/800358/why-am-i-getting-this-wcf-error-message)

Comment: my array is of type string. shouldn't wcf already know it ? and just recognize it ? i don't have a custom class with datacontract.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For others who get to the same error, the fix was to add :`[ServiceKnownType(typeof(string[]))]` in my interface class.

For  more information about this problem you can read : [HERE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.serviceknowntypeattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)