# WCF There was an error while trying to serialize parameter

Tags: wcf, entity-framework

I get the following error when try to bind the data to the gridview. I also using entity framework auto generated entities. At first the error show is The underlying connection was closed: The connection was closed unexpectedly when debug using wcf-traces, I getting error above. Here are my codes.

The error function

```
   Public Function GetProductList() Implements IProductService.GetProductList

            Dim Db As New BMEntities

            Dim data = From p In Db.SC_PRODUCT _
                       select p
            Return data
     End Function
```

The working which can bind the data

```
Public Function GetProductList() As IEnumerable(Of SC_PRODUCT) Implements IProductService.GetProductList

        Dim Db As New BMEntities

        Dim data = From p In Db.SC_PRODUCT _
                   select p
        Return data.AsEnumerable
 End Function
```

WebSites

```
 Private Sub RadGrid1_NeedDataSource(sender As Object, e As GridNeedDataSourceEventArgs) Handles RadGrid1.NeedDataSource
        Dim ws As New ProductWS.ProductServiceClient

        Dim Data = ws.GetProductList
        RadGrid1.DataSource = Data
End Sub
```

Anyone please help. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like problem with data contract. This question is already answred. Add KnownType attrible like mentioned in this link 
[Why am I getting this WCF Error Message?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/800358/why-am-i-getting-this-wcf-error-message)

```
[DataContract]
[KnownType(typeof(string[]))]
public class YourClassNameHere
{
}
```

Comment: Where should I put the code above ? It is put above the auto generated  entities class. Thanks

Comment: Hi, did you read the page I have linked? It is explained quite clearly there. [1]:http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa347850.aspx     [2]:http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sowmy/archive/2006/06/06/all-about-knowntypes.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Did you thoroughly check the WCf trace log? Often this error occurs if there is some class,field property which is not serialized (does not have DataMember/EnumMember) attribute as evident from error messages

Please check if there are any enums which you want to pass back to client and it does not have EnumMember attribute